# How to treat the date in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have this dataframe: this is just a snapshot.

```
     TimeStart           TimeEnd              Value
  17-10-2013 14:31:26  17-10-2013 14:46:18     36.09
  18-10-2013 17:52:15  19-10-2013 4:23:52      1.32
  19-10-2013 17:10:29  19-10-2013 22:01:25     1271
  20-10-2013 19:20:47  20-10-2013 22:42:38     10736
  21-10-2013 15:47:55  21-10-2013 20:22:21     0.009
  22-10-2013 19:45:47  23-10-2013 7:24:43      600
```

I want to convert it to create a data frame which looks like this, where column H01.01 indicates the 1st hour (H01) and the first ten minutes (.01) of the day. It goes up to H24.06. Instead of 0, for each date, I want to fill it with the value column.
[image]

My issue is that it's hard to allocate the "Value" into each time interval of hour/min (H1.01, H1.02..etc) since the TimeStart and TimeEnd starts and ends at a random time. Also, DateStart and DateEnd can be longer than 1 day, which means I need to come up with a way to transfer the "value" into the following day.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The first thing that comes to my mind is that there is probably a simpler way of doing this if you change your approach.

Comment: Some of the simpler approach i thought was rather than having 10min time interval per day (currently, it goes from H01.01 to H24.06), having a 1hour interval might be easier. And then, using the 1) using the split function,  split(df, cut(df$TimeEnd,"hour")) and putting the "Value" column according to the each time of the day. Problem with this approach is that, it doesn't take into account of the minutes and the seconds.